# How to format \ref output as word instead of as number?

Tags: formatting, ref

I have a requirement in a document of class `book` with which I'm working that requires **all** numbers below 10 (0 until 9, but not negative numbers I presume) to be written as a word.

So in my document, I have chapter headings to which I refer using `\ref{}`. And as per this requirement, these references must also be written as a word (i.e. Chapter One instead of Chapter 1).

I've looked around the net for some hints, and I've found that one can use the package `fmtcount` to format numbers (within a certain range) as words. In particular, `\Numberstring{}` and `\Numberstringnum{}` were used. This does seem to work with the `\ref{}`command when using `\Numberstringnum{}`. A minimal working example is provided below

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter \ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cchapref}[1]{Chapter \Numberstring{\ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ccchapref}[1]{Chapter \Numberstringnum{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{} \label{ch1}

A reference to \chapref{ch1}, but not to \cchapref{ch1}, however, it is one to \ccchapref{ch1}.

\end{document}
```

With the following output

[image: Snippet of the compiled document with acceptable answer]

If one tries this MWE including the package `hyperref` (which I also have in my document), this solution breaks. A sample output is provided

[image: Snippet of the compiled document with error]

Has anyone got an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Even without the hyperref package, I can't seem to get your MWE to compile.

Comment: Your definition of `\cchapref` is a bit odd: the use of `\Numberstring` doesn't seem to match of its documented use?

Comment: that is a common convention when applying to externally counted things "two towns" v "1000 towns" but it makes no sense to use it when referring to section headings that explicitly use digits  within the same document. Are you sure that the rules are being interpreted correctly here????

Comment: If **all** single digit numbers must be represented as words why `Chapter 1` not `Chapter one` or `Chapter One`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems odd to apply the requirement to chapter numbers, which are just *labels* and not numbers in the sense of “objects for counting”.

Are you also required to number pages from 1 to 9 in words? I don't think so.

---

You can use `refcount`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cchapref}[1]{Chapter~\hyperref[#1]{\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title} \label{ch1}

A reference to \chapref{ch1} and to \cchapref{ch1}.

\end{document}
```

If you don't load `hyperref`, the second command should simply be

```
\newcommand{\cchapref}[1]{Chapter~\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}
```

In the picture, the red rectangles show links.

[image]

---

A slightly different version, where `\chapref` uses words for chapters from 1 to 9; there is also `\cchapref` to force words in any case.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{%
  Chapter~%
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{#1}<10
    \hyperref[#1]{\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
  \else
    \ref{#1}%
  \fi
  }
\newcommand{\cchapref}[1]{Chapter~\hyperref[#1]{\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title} \label{ch1}

A reference to \chapref{ch1} and to \cchapref{ch1}.

A reference to \chapref{ch12} and to \cchapref{ch12}.

\setcounter{chapter}{11}

\chapter{Title}\label{ch12}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "It seems odd to apply the requirement to chapter numbers, [...]" - yea, I'm just rolling my eyes, but requirements are requirements.